# Which is the best way to get the orientation angle for each direction (Forward, Right, Left, Backward)

Tags: angles, direction

I'm running into an issue for a while.
The best way to find the orientation angle between 4 directions in a strafe locomotion mode.

The character can move around in 4 directions. Having a velocity vector direction from [-180, 180] I need to know how much I have to rotate the character for each direction.

I mean, in case we are looking forward, our direction will be 0. So if the direction is -45, I should rotate the character 45 degrees.

Otherwise, if we are looking right (90 degrees) and my direction is 80 I should rotate -10 degrees.

I've been trying different solutions but I want to have the best solution.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: _I'm running into an issue for a while._ You don't describe any issue. What is the issue you're having? _I've been trying different solutions but I want to have the best solution._ It appears you have a solution that works. What makes you believe you don't already have the best solution for your own situation? Giving random solutions to non-issues is not our specialty, we're here to fix actual issues, so please edit your question so that it shows what's troubling you.

Comment: Are you just looking for a formula to get the signed angular difference between two headings, like `((target - current + 540) % 360) - 180`?

Comment: Yes, more or less. The thing is I don't know what target is. I only know what direction is the character facing (Fwd, Right, Left o Backward)